# Boto3 profile creation: botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile could not be found

Tags: python, boto3, aws-batch

I am trying to run python code on a remote serverless server which does not have an aws profile setup. After looking at the boto3 documentation it looks like if I say:

```
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='dev') 

client = session.client(service_name="secretsmanager",
        region_name=region_name 
) 
get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name 
)
```

I will get a new boto3 name profile but instead I get an error:

> secret_class = get_secret(name, region, profile)
>
> File "/metaflow/func_get_aws_secrets.py", line 45, in get_secret   session
>   = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=profile)
>
> ...
>
> raise ProfileNotFound(profile=profile_name)
>
> botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (dev) could not be found

I don't understand what it missing?

Comment: Specifying profile_name in Session does not create a profile, rather it tries to use the profile with that name. If you are able to modify the .aws/config or .aws/credentials folder on the remote server then you can create a profile called dev. Otherwise, use environment variables for your aws creds or specify them when you create the session. For more info read through [this page](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#method-parameters)

Comment: You are correct I was reading that incorrectly! Session does not create a session if it doesn't exist and that is how i coded it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening is that you are trying to get a `Session` with a profile named `dev`.

If you want to know more about aws profiles, you can try this: [Named Profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html)

If you want to keep your code, you'll need to add a profile named dev in your credentials file:

- `~/.aws/credentials` (Linux/Mac)
- `%USERPROFILE%\.aws\credentials` (Windows)

Your credentials file will be something like:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=
aws_secret_access_key=

[dev]
aws_access_key_id=
aws_secret_access_key=
```

If you don't want to create dev profile, just remove the `profile_name` argument, and it will use your default configuration

Comment: how would you translate these to env variables ? e.g what is the env variable corresponding to 'dev'